# Get value from sublist using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have classes `Item` and `Product`

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public Product[] product{ get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id;
    public string productname;
}
```

I got these details as `List<Item> lstItem = new List<Item>();`.My challenge is I want to get `productname` from this list with condition `id` is not zero.So I try with linq but I cannot get result. please help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SelectMany` to flatten the inner collections and then filter them

```
var result = lstItem.SelectMany(item => item.product)
                    .Where(product => product.Id != 0)
                    .Select(product => product.productname);
```

Or in query syntax:

```
var result = from item in lstItem
             from product in item.Product
             where product.Id != 0
             select product.productname;
```

The `result` is an `IEnumerable<string>`. To get a single `string` containing all the values:

```
string concatenatedProductNames = string.Join(", ", result);
```

---

*Also I'd recommend changing your classes to match the [C# naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx):*

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Product[] Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I got result as System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[App.Product,System.String]

Comment: @user7063016 - I assume you just did `ToString` but the result isn't a string but a collection of strings. See update above

Comment: How to get one value from result?

Comment: @user7063016 - Or the way I showed above... Or if you really just want 1 use `.FirstOrDefault()`